# I'm getting errors when trying to import and use ngx-qrcode2 in my angular 14 app to create qr codes. Is there a better lib?

Tags: angular, qr-code

Getting an error when running npm install

npm install ngx-qrcode2 --save

npm install ngx-qrcode2 --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: tslib@2.6.2
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.3.0" from @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@">=6.0.0 || <=10.0.0" from ngx-qrcode2@9.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-qrcode2
npm ERR!       ngx-qrcode2@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (@angular/core, rxjs, zone.js)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from ngx-qrcode2@9.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-qrcode2
npm ERR!   ngx-qrcode2@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/geigersoft/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/geigersoft/.npm/_logs/2023-09-22T04_37_25_751Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

you can try to clean the cache using this command:
npm cache clean --force, then delete the node_module directory and also delete package-lock.json and then try to reinstall the package. i hope this will work.